# MySQL commit trigger done

Tags: python, mysql

I have MySQL database where I'm loading big files which insert more than 190 000 rows. I'm using python script which is doing some stuff and then load data from csv file into mysql execute query and commit.

My question is if I'm sending such a big file, is database ready after commit command or how to trigger when all datas are inserted in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COMMIT` does not actually return until the data has been... committed... so, yes, once you have committed any transaction, the work from that transaction is entirely done, as far as your application is concerned.